# How to add columns that shows the total number of rows in a table with condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got this table and I wish to add columns that summarized it:

table now:

| Name | PAT_ID | Has_T | Has_Y | Has_G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brian | 123 | X |  | X |
| Brian | 356 | X | X |  |
| Brian | 3546 |  | X | X |
| Brian | 987 | X |  |  |

What I wish is to add columns that counts stuff in the table and give a value in each row:

Desired output:

| Name | PAT_ID | Has_T | Has_Y | Has_G | Total_T | Total_Y | Total_PATS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brian | 123 | X |  | X | 3 | 2 | 4 |
| Brian | 356 | X | X |  | 3 | 2 | 4 |
| Brian | 3546 |  | X | X | 3 | 2 | 4 |
| Brian | 987 | X |  |  | 3 | 2 | 4 |

Someone helped me with the last one (Total_PATS) with counting all row with:

```
 COUNT(*) OVER () AS [total]      << for all rows.
```

how to do it with conditions? I have 'X' so I want to count all the rows where has_T has an X...

Comment: Change the `*` to `Has_T`, `Has_Y`, etc...

Comment: It doesnt work... it still counts all the rows

Comment: Are the "blank" rows not `NULL` values?

Comment: no. they are blank or space... and are supposed to stay like that

Comment: is there a way to count all 'X' in a column?

Comment: Then `NULLIF` the value first, and then `COUNT` it. I.e. `NULLIF(Has_T,'')` Though, honestly, switching to `NULL` would be a better solution.

Comment: I cant... I need it to stay like that. is there any other option? counting all 'X' only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use conditional count with `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
name, pat_id, has_t, has_y, has_g,
COUNT (CASE WHEN has_t = 'X' THEN 1 END) OVER() AS Total_T,
COUNT (CASE WHEN has_y = 'X' THEN 1 END) OVER() AS Total_Y,
COUNT (CASE WHEN has_g = 'X' THEN 1 END) OVER() AS Total_G,
COUNT (*) OVER() AS Total_PATS
FROM yourtable;
```

This will count `X` values only.

As already said in comments, using `NULL` rather than spaces/empty strings would be much better, for example because COUNT ignores `NULL`, so we could simply write `COUNT(has_t)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

As you are storing blank values, or values of spaces, the `COUNT` will still count those valuesl `COUNT` *counts* non-`NULL` values. Ideally, you should be storing `NULL`, not `''`, `' '` (or even `'     '`) in such values, it makes `COUNT`ing the values much easier.

You could, however, `NULL` the values in the `COUNT`:

```sql
SELECT name,
       pat_id,
       has_t,
       has_y,
       has_g,
       COUNT(NULLIF(has_t,'')) OVER() AS total_t,
       COUNT(NULLIF(has_y,'')) OVER() AS total_y,
       COUNT(NULLIF(has_g,'')) OVER() AS total_g,
       COUNT(*) OVER() AS total
FROM dbo.Yourtable;
```